# Cleaning Mould Away & Inhibition of Future Mould Growth

Tags: walls

I am an ordinary, non chemistry minded person. Never before have I had to deal with mould growth in a damp house. Now I do.
I had an idea regarding the efficacy of cleaning this mould off the walls in my bathroom and bedroom. A simple solution of sodium hydroxide in water. Will this work?
Furthermore, will the same solution, (a fresh solution though, not the same one used to initially clean the mould away) inhibit future mould growth?
If not, any ideas on what will inhibit future mould growth? Thank you.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Keep your RH reasonable - use a dehumidifier.  Even if mold isn't growing with high RH fungus and dust mites are.

Answer (score 3):

Mold requires two things:

1. Organic matter (i.e. food)
2. Water

You prevent mold by eliminating one or both of these.  In many cases the food is the building materials themselves, wood, paper, some paints, etc.  So you have to focus on the water or moisture that is allowing the mold to take hold and grow.

A diluted bleach solution is useful for cleaning up but it will not inhibit future growth if the conditions are again favorable. Commercial mold removing products are also available.

In difficult cases you can get paint additives that are designed to inhibit mold and mildew growth.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.